# Aborted (core dumped) Error

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm subscribing to RBG kinect topic (/camera/rgb/image_color) and depth topic (/camera/depth_registered/image_raw) and I try to blend the two images like this

[image: image description]

using this code that I get from opencv doc:

```
double a = 0.5; double b; 
Mat blend;
a = ( 1.0 - b );    
addWeighted( cv_ptr_kinect_rgb->image, alpha, cv_ptr_kinect_depth->image, 0.5, 0.5, blend);
cv::imshow( "Linear Blend", blend);
```

but I get this error message:

```
 /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = cv_bridge::CvImage]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't really know what going wrong !?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187529/aborted-(core-dumped)-error/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-23**:
One of you image pointers is probably null.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-23**:
I don't think so because I can visualize the two topics before blending them. (I post the topic that I use)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-23**:
Then "something else" is null. You should check the stack trace in a debugger to see where the null access is caused.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-23**:
How can I do that ?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-23**:
@dornhege you are right this error comes from a null pointer. Thank y'll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look here http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vik748](https://answers.ros.org/users/29926/vik748/) on 2017-10-12**:
this link is dead!!